# Mysql Rename Only End of Urls

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find and rename in mysql database, I've command like this :

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_id = REPLACE(meta_id, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv"), 
    post_id = REPLACE(post_id, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv"), 
    meta_key = REPLACE(meta_key, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv"), 
    meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv")
```

I need to rename ALL `" -SITE- "` to `" -SITE-.mkv "`, only add `.mkv` extension to `" -SITE- "`, But there is a problem here .

We have another `"-SITE-.mkv"` in our tables before doing this. If I want to search `-SITE-`, this command will rename old parameters to `-SITE-.mkv.mkv`.

How can I find and rename ONLY parameters without `.mkv` at the END ?

I just need find `-SITE-` without `.mkv` and add `.mkv` at the end.

Any one can help me ?

Thank you

Comment: can you break your one update query into many update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include the `WHERE` clause, and have the option to combine it with `NOT LIKE '%value%`. The percent signs are wild cards, and because you're only interested in the columns ending with .mkv, you only need the first one to include anything before .mkv.

To make it a bit clearer, I split your query into four statements.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_id = REPLACE(meta_id, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE meta_id NOT LIKE '%.mkv';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET post_id = REPLACE(post_id, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE post_id NOT LIKE '%.mkv';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_key = REPLACE(meta_key, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE meta_key NOT LIKE '%.mkv';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE meta_value NOT LIKE '%.mkv';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break your query into multiple query

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_id = REPLACE(meta_id, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE meta_id ='-SITE-';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET post_id = REPLACE(post_id, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE post_id ='-SITE-';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_key = REPLACE(meta_key, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE meta_key ='-SITE-';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, "-SITE-", "-SITE-.mkv") WHERE meta_value ='-SITE-';
```